# How to retrieve data with zeros in eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am creating a student number from retrieving multiple data from database.

Like **Course_ID.Year_Code.Student_no**

In order to retrieve same digit numbers I fill my raw student number (which is given on creation) as 0001, 0002.

When I try to retrieve my student number by getting this number from database

I get results without zeros.

Lets say  **Course_ID 22** and **Year_Code 16**

and **Student_NO 0005**

I return number as **22165** which should be **22160005**.
this is how I get students.

```
$students = \App\Student::with('payment')->where('branch', $id)->get();
```

(I actually recieve student_no without zeros with the query below)

and this is how I write in blade

```
<td>{{$student->Course_ID.$student->course->year_code.$student->student_no}}  </td>
```

**PS: I do know how to retrieve numbers with native php by using str_pad. I ask if there is a method to do it on Eloquent.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do that that Eloquent would offer so you'd need to add some logic yourself.

One option would be to store **student_no** as a string in the database, otherwise zeros will be lost when it's fetched as an integer in PHP, as PHP doesn't care about your **ZEROFILL** and treats **0005** as **5**.

Another option is to append zeros manually in PHP after fetching data from the database, e.g. by adding an accessor in your model:

```
public function getStudentNoAttribute() {
  return sprintf("%05d", $this->attributes['student_no']);
}
```

This way, whenever you access **student_no** attribute of your model it would be converted to zero-filled string automatically.

Comment: I have actually prefer str_pad with 4 zeros I wonder if native way on eloquent to do that thank you

Comment: str_pad will work as well. And the accessor above is in my opinion the best way to do that. That's what custom accessors are for in Eloquent - to convert whatever comes from the database to format you want to use in your application.

Comment: shouldn't getSTudentNoAttribute receive a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for any property on an Eloquent model. This allows you to modify that property as it is being returned.

The convention for creating an accessor is to create a method starting with `get`,then add the property name, then add `Attribute`. So for instance, you could call one `getStudentNoAttribute`. Add this to your Student model:

```
function getStudentNoAttribute() {
    return str_pad($this->student_no,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Add a function like this for every property you want to adjust with the zeroes. Then every time you call `$student->student_no` on an instance of your `Student` model, it will be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

create the column in the table as STUDENT_NO INT(5) ZEROFILL and then any numbers smaller than 10000 would have leading zeros as necessary when queried
5 would show as 00005 for example and 4124 would show as 04124 etc.

Comment: I do store student_no with zerofill but retrieving data has no zeros

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems good, but [Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) require a value be passed to the function, or you will run into some issues. This is probably a more recent change, but I think it is worth mentioning. So, the answer would then become:

```
public function getStudentNoAttribute($value) {
    return sprintf("%05d", $value);
}
```

or, as [@Andy Noelker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5455309/andy-noelker)'s answer says:

```
function getStudentNoAttribute($value) {
    return str_pad($value,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```