# Define property zerofill and size on field schema migration with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I define property zerofill and size (2) on field schema migration with Laravel?

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('reference')->length(2);
});
```

and this field with zerofill.

I would like use my seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    Book::create
    ([
        'reference' => 01
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zerofill is not a SQL standard. The shema builder of laravel provides only these ANSI SQL standards.

But you can use a workaround to define it with a raw sql statement:

create_books.php

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('reference');
});
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE books CHANGE reference reference INT(2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL');
```

Comment: You can do this with an accessor. [Similar Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800053/how-to-retrieve-data-with-zeros-in-eloquent)

The question is: is it necessary to store it with leading zeros in the database if you have to fill it up manually in an accessor?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, in order to keep your migrations portable, you'll want to use an accessor to provide that.  It'll look something like this:

Book.php model

```
public function getReferenceAttribute($value)
{
    if($value){
        return str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```