# keep zerofill format in the JSON repsonse with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

How can I keep zerofill format in ths JSON repsonse ?

I have in my database a 'reference' field with zerofill property.
In my controller I have this :

```
return response()->json(['data' => $book], 200);
```

And my JSON is :

```
data: {
    id: 3,
    reference: 3,
}
```

I would like this :

```
data: {
    id: 3,
    reference: 03,
}
```

Comment: You'll need to send it as a string.

Comment: use an accessor as I  mentioned in your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108133/define-property-zerofill-and-size-on-field-schema-migration-with-laravel/35108232#comment57938116_35108232)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `$book->reference` is numeric rather than a string. You can use [`str_pad`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to left pad it with zeros

```
$book->reference = str_pad($book->reference, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT);
return response()->json(['data' => $book], 200);
```