# Cannot save last four digits of the card to database

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating payment integration in Laravel. In there I want to save the last 4 digits of the card to the database. Here is the array I used to save the data to the database.

```
 $return_code = Payment::where('id', $transactionId)->update([
            'return_code' => $status,
            'return_message' => $status == 'success'? 'Successfully Captured': 'Payment Failed - ' .$errorMessage,
            'tx_ref' => $transactionReference,
            'transaction_amount' => !empty($amount) ? $amount : 0.00,
            'brand' => $cardType,
            'last4' => str_pad(substr($maskedPAN, -4), strlen(4), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT),
            'holder' => $cardholderName,
            'expiry' => $expiry,
            'payment_gateway' => 3,
        ]);

        return $status == 'success'?true : false;
```

From this code, it saves the last four digits to the database, only if the **last four digits start without zero**. It means if the card number is as 4111 1111 1111 **1**111 it saves to the database as **1111**.

But, if the **last four digits of the card starts with zero**, it saves only **111** to the database. It means if the card number is as 4000 4000 0000 **0**111 it saves only **111** to the database.

Please help me to save the last four digits of the card even if the last four digits start with zero as 4000 4000 0000 **0**111.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the data type of `last4`? Int? If so you need to change to varchar(4).

Comment: Yes, it is int(4) , But this is a live project and cannot change the data type from database as there is another payment integration is running. Aren't there another option that we can do from the code?

Comment: Not anything that's fundamentally safe. This isn't integer data. The other payment integration shouldn't matter; it's "last 4" shouldn't be an integer either. Why can't you do a change to the column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `int` as datatype will remove the zeroes on the left.

If you need to keep it you should change to varchar.

In laravel you can create a migration to change it (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('myTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('last4', 4)->change();
    });
}
```

You may need to run `composer require doctrine/dbal`

If you can't change the column data type, another option would be to convert the data to string on runtime and use `str_pad()` function, but I don't think this is a good option here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you're using MySQL.

Since your column it's a `INT` you can't because it's a number and the number isn't saved with zeros on the left unless you specify the `ZEROFILL` int column. What you can do is modify it, `ALTER` the column and add the `ZEROFILL` to the column (Not changing the type) to fill with zeros when the number it's less than 4 digits.

Also, `INT(4)` doesn't mean that only accept 0 or 4 digits, you can even store 20 or more than 4 digits, it's range doesn't change, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes) to understand it better.

Comment: Here is my code. If I add the ZEROFILL to the ‘ last4’ column how should I proceed? Please help me.


`public function up()
{
    Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('last4')->nullable();
    });
}`

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer. I think you already achieve it and found a solution to your problem but here is a link about what I was talking if you want to see:https://stackoverflow.com/a/35108232

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the type of the table field from `int` to `varchar`, a better solution would be to store your value as an `int` like so

```
$return_code = Payment::where('id', $transactionId)->update([
               // other fields
               'last4' => (int)substr($maskedPAN, -4),
               // other fields
               ]);

return $status == 'success'?true : false;
```

Then, always use a method that returns the required number of digits to retrieve the `last4` field from `Payment`

```
function getLast4($intval) {
    return str_pad($intval, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$var = Payment::where('id', $transactionId)->pluck('last4');
$last4 = getLast4($var[0]);
```